# Receiving notifications of new posts on Twitter via a specific URL

Tags: twitter

I would like to access the messages in the Twitter via the API in real time. A cursory search showed that it is possible to periodically send API-request to Twitter. In general, this is possible. 15 requests in 15 minutes is enough.
But I'm wondering, are there other ways to get information faster?
For example, is it possible to subscribe to notifications and receive a request from Twitter at a certain address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking if Twitter has webhooks? The answer is [yes](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/guides/getting-started-with-webhooks)

- Review Securing Webhooks documention taking special note of the
  Challenge Response Check (CRC) requirements.
- Create a web app with an endpoint to use as your webhook to receive
  events (e.g. https://example.com/webhook/twitter).
- Make sure your webhook supports POST requests for incoming events and
  GET requests for the CRC.
- Register your webhook URL with your app using POST
  account_activity/webhooks.
- Use the returned webhook_id to add user subscriptions with POST
  account_activity/webhooks/:webhook_id/subscriptions.